# How do I get over the following error about std::vector<bool>?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

It seems that `vector<bool>` doesn't work like usual vectors

```
auto it = find(flags.rbegin(), flags.rend(), false);

flags.erase(it+1, flags.end());
```

I want to delete the elements that come (strictly) after the first false from the end. The code (only the 2nd line) produces a long template error, the last line is :

> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_bvector.h:1025:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::reverse_iterator’ to ‘std::vector::const_iterator {aka std::_Bit_const_iterator}’

Answer (score 3):

You mix two types of iterator in your erase call, while it expects two compatible iterator that define a range to be deleted.

I guess that is what u want:

```
 std::vector<bool> flags({false, true, false, true, true});
 auto it = std::find(flags.rbegin(), flags.rend(), false);

 flags.erase(std::next(it.base()), flags.end());
```

Comment: You were faster, have a +1

Comment: I think `std::next` shouldn't be used because OP said "I want to delete the elements that come (strictly) after the first false from the end."; `it.base()` is pointing to the element after the 1st `false` element from the end.

Answer (score 0):

While `std::vector<bool>` indeed does not work like normal vectors at all, this particular issue is not related to its idio(syncra)cy.

Reverse iterators and forward iterators on the same range are different types: they are not directly compatible.

Since `it` is found from `rbegin()` and `rend()`, it's a reverse iterator. Note: this also means `it + 1` is closer to the beginning of `flags` than `it` is.

What you need to do is convert the reverse iterator to its underyling normal iterator:

```
flags.erase(it.base() + 1, flags.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first line you are getting a **reverse_iterator** because you are using *rbegin()* and *rend()* functions in the find(). However, *flags.erase()* **expects a std::vector::const_iterator**, and therefore you get the type mismatch in the first argument.

Consider finding the first false value with *cbegin()* and *cend()* functions, such as:

```
auto it = find(flags.cbegin(), flags.cend(), false);
```

PS: Also consider checking if the value of iterator it is not the last one in the vector to avoid trying to erase something that doesn't exist.